# Clear old log entries from API while saving N of each type by user

Tags: mysql

I have a log table that quickly gets over 20 GB and was hoping to develop a cron job that clears out the old entries while keeping the last 100 of each type for each user.

```
 id     |   user_id   |      api_route
1506          304           api/trayapp
1504          379           api/trayapp
1502          321           api/trayapp
1496          377           api/servers
1494          382           api/trayapp
1485          289           api/trayapp
1483          235           api/trayapp
1481          318           api/trayapp
1480          296           api/trayapp
1477          117           api/trayapp
1474          311           api/trayapp
1470          312           api/servers
1467          298           api/servers
1465          377           api/trayapp
1464          303           api/servers
1463          313           api/servers
1462          102           api/servers
1461          127           api/servers
1459          383           api/servers
1458          312           api/trayapp
1457          378           api/servers
1454          308           api/servers
1453          197           api/servers
1452          298           api/trayapp
1448          100           api/servers
1447          317           api/trayapp
1435          320           api/trayapp
1434          103           api/servers
1432          211           api/servers
1431          303           api/trayapp
1429          313           api/trayapp
1428          102           api/trayapp
1425          308           api/trayapp
1423          127           api/trayapp
1422          378           api/trayapp
1416          383           api/trayapp
1414          295           api/servers
1407          380           api/servers
1402          197           api/trayapp
1399          379           api/servers
1397          100           api/trayapp
1393          321           api/servers
1388          304           api/servers
1386          319           api/servers
1384          103           api/trayapp
1379          211           api/trayapp
1378          229           api/servers
1376          289           api/servers
1375          381           api/trayapp
1373          304           api/trayapp
1372          296           api/servers
1371          380           api/trayapp
1370          295           api/trayapp
1368          382           api/servers
1367          235           api/servers
1366          117           api/servers
```

I know I need to do a `DELETE WHERE NOT IN (SELECT...` but my first thought of how to do the select would be to use GROUP_CONCAT on the id, but then how would you use the results in the `WHERE NOT IN`? What would be your preferred method of removing all but the most recent? I do have created_at fields available but since the id is auto incremented it seems irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it using DENSE_RANK and PARTITION. This will clear everything but the most recent 100 of each type for each user

```
DELETE FROM logs WHERE id NOT in (
SELECT id
FROM (
  SELECT
    id, user_id, url,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, url ORDER BY id DESC) AS r
  FROM logs
    WHERE user_id is not NULL
) AS t
WHERE t.r <= 100
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not going to be that simple.

Instead, write a script that walks through the table using the index on `user_id` for keeping track of where it is.

For each user, find the 100th from last, then `DELETE` any older ones.

This script will take minutes or hours, but who cares.  The script could even start over when it finishes -- keep going forever.

It will be desirable to have

```
INDEX(user_id, dt)
```

(I am assuming `dt` is the column giving the order within the user.)

More details...

The loop starts with finding the next $user_id:

```
SELECT user_id FROM tbl  WHERE user_id > $last_user_id
    ORDER BY user_id  LIMIT 1;
```

To find the 100th newest:

```
SELECT dt FROM tbl  WHERE user_id = $user_id
    ORDER BY user_id DESC  LIMIT 100,1
```

If that comes back empty, there is nothing to delete for this $user_id.  Else, use the return value ($dt) and do:

```
DELETE FROM tbl  WHERE user_id = $user_id  AND dt < $dt;
```

It might work to combine the `SELECT` and `DELETE` thus:

```
DELETE FROM tbl  WHERE user_id = $user_id
    ORDER BY user_id DESC  LIMIT 100, 99999
```

That says skip 100, then delete the next 99990 rows (working backward).

I have more discussion [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig) .

(I have successfully implemented a similar script in a 200GB table.)